# Question about the definition of information bottleneck

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, mutual-information

I've read some interpreting "information bottleneck" as the loss of information of X regarding a random variable Y when a compressed random variable T is used.

Could you please explain why the definition uses:

$$
I(X;T) - \beta I(T;Y)
$$

and not

$$
I(X;Y) - \beta I(T;Y)
$$

Comment: Can you please provide a source? Where did you read this?

Comment: @Asterion "The information bottleneck describes a constrained optimisation objective where the goal is to maximise the mutual information between the latent bottleneck Z and the task Y while discarding all the irrelevant information about Y that might be present in the input X."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure we're understanding the variables correctly, you are already given the two variables $X$ and $Y$ and know they are correlated. You are trying to come up with the optimal compression of $X$ (called $T$) that still has the relevant information about $Y$.

So, $I(X; Y)$ is fixed. It doesn't make sense to include it in your optimization.

Where does the bottleneck come from? You want to maximize the amount of information that gets transmitted, $I(T; Y)$. You could just put $T=X$, but this wastes bits on features of $X$ that might not be relevant. So you also want to maximize $H(X|T)$, which equals $H(X) - I(X; T)$. As $H(X)$ is fixed your overall problem is
$$\text{Maximize}\quad I(T; Y),\qquad\text{and minimize}\quad I(X;T).$$
Letting $\beta$ be the tradeoff parameter, you get
$$\text{Maximize}\quad\beta I(T; Y) - I(X; T).$$

I'd also recommend reading the original paper, "[The Information Bottleneck Method](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0004057)" by Tishby et al.